# Firebase - How to handle firestore & API changes in previous app versions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase in an app which we deployed a couple of months ago. Of course, a few database changes happened and a lot of new triggers were created, which we now want to deploy to production together with a new app version.

The question is how do we force the previous app version to work with the new triggers and database structure without forcing our users to update the old app? Does anyone have any experience or suggestions in implementing this smoothly?

Some examples of what did change:

- A counter to keep track of like counts was set in the app code in the previous version. This now has been moved to a cloud function.
- A collection named '/users' is now split in two collections '/users' and '/_users', with '/users' containing all data accessible for all users and '/_users' containing all data only accessible for admins. Also a trigger is built to keep corresponding fields synchronized (fe. the field firstName occurs in '/users' and '/_users') So when a new user is created in the previous app version, the document will contain too many fields, because some belong to the '/_users' collection now. How can this be handled?

I've found out that with remote config we'll be able to force the users to update the app, but still that ain't the way to go for us. The first scenario seems easy to counter by just recalculating the count in the trigger. The second seems a little more complex.

Comment: Without seeing the specific scenario that you're struggling with, it's hard to answer concretely. But in general you'll want to us Cloud Functions to close the gap between old and new clients. So they fill in any data that the old clients won't write, correct any data that older clients write differently, and remove any data that the old clients write extra.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is correct! I will add this to the question.

Comment: I think the best is support for 2 type of user, old and new, just like facebook and some bigger company. Telling user to switch to new version instead of old version by give them some beautiful feature is better than force them  to update.